# Picking out the alephs

Tags: hebrew, text

How can you quickly pick out all the [alephs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleph#Hebrew%5FAleph) on a page of Hebrew printed text?

Comment: Dare I ask how this came up?

Comment: Close? Will anyone without an answer ask this?

Comment: @msh210: {petulantly} *Maybe* someone would.

Comment: Check stackoverflow.com using Python.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a programming question not a judaism question. use stackoverflow.com

Comment: @sabbahillel, I agree that this question is not clearly about Judaism and therefore deserves closure. It has nothing to do with programming, though. Just out of curiosity, what brought this old question to your attention now?

Comment: @IsaacMoses For some reason it popped up in Review I did not notice the date. I thought that review only popped up new questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turn the lower-right corner of the text toward you and up toward your eyes, so that you'll be looking at the text from an oblique angle. The alephs will seem to pop out of the page. I think it's because they uniquely have a major line running top-left to bottom-right.

Comment: What were you doing when you noticed this?  Is there a practical application?

Comment: I noticed it years ago in shul. I don't remember why I was looking diagonally and obliquely at my siddur, but I was. I don't think I've ever had a practical need to pick out all the alephs on a page, but I'm sure such needs exist from time to time.

Comment: It sometimes works with tzadis too, although the angle of declension can vary with fonts.

Comment: WAF, did you notice this phenomenon independently?

Comment: Off-topic doesn't mean it cannot be pretty cool ! Took me a while to make it work though. I wonder how many non-MY readers in the entire world know this?

Comment: lol this is active again 'cause Im commenting